# "Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string" error in php insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I run this code I get the error "Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string" on the line where I declare a new mysqli object. I can't find the error no matter how many times I read it over.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   echo $_POST['course'],
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","sec_user","Uzg82t=u%#bNgPJw","GPA_Tracker");
   $user = $_SESSION['username'];
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into assessment_type (username, courseID, assessment, percentage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
   $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $user, $_POST['course'], $_POST['assesment'], $_POST['percentage']);
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: `echo $_POST['course'],` should be `echo $_POST['course'];`

Comment: It's trying to echo `$mysqli` because of the comma.

Comment: funny what a bad copy/paste will do, just to speed things up

Comment: `echo` allows multiple arguments, comma-separated, so... `echo $_POST, new mysqli`... you're trying to echo our your mysqli object.

Comment: and probably a typo in `assesment` in the POST array which the proper spelling is "assessment". http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assessment - If so, error reporting will tell you, since your column is called `assessment`.

Comment: and who knows if the session's even been started (insert question mark here...) Edit: but it probably is, since you wouldn't be getting that notice.

Comment: *I'm out of this loop*

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is where you have the problem:

```
echo $_POST['course'], //notice the comma, rather than a semi-colon ";"
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","sec_user","Uzg82t=u%#bNgPJw","GPA_Tracker");
```

The `echo` statement/construct accepts a comma-separated list of statements, hence coming across the `,` it thinks the next statement following it is also to be echoed. As it turns out, that next statement is an object-creation statement, whereas `echo` accepts only strings.

To fix the error, properly close your `echo $_POST['course']` with a semicolon like below:

```
echo $_POST['course'];
```

Comment: better solution, just remove `echo $_POST['course'],` altogether; it's not needed.

Comment: Exactly, @Fred-ii-, you are right. I left it there so the OP could see the point I was trying to make.

Comment: see a few new comments I left the OP ;-)